# Passing data from javascript into .erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to know if this is possible. I have a bit of javascript code that renders a page based on information from my Rails 2.3.17 application. This code is inherited and not my own. The problem is that I am trying to get data from the server about an object that I do not know about during run time. Basically I am trying to do this:

```
var record_id = 73; 
if(<%= DataTable.find(record_id).value_of_record.nil? %>{
    ...
}else{
    ...
```

where the record_id is what I want to pass into the .erb selection at run time with javascript. Is this possible. And if not, is there any way I can call the information from javascript to get the id of the record passed inside the .erb file? The id is currently being stored in the html document.

Comment: No, it is not possible. You could pass a Ruby variable to Javascript, but the reverse can't be done this way. You need Ajax (make a request to the server with the record_id and do you ruby rails checks there, and send the answer back to javascript).

Comment: I'm trying to do that now. Do you know how to get the result of a query back using prototype.js? That is apparently what they are using and I don't know the proper syntax for the query string.

Comment: Arf I don't know prototype.js very well... Do you have jQuery in your App? What is your Rails version you are using?

Comment: I'm using rails 2.3.11. And the app uses prototype.js exclusively. It's kind of old.

Comment: This can help: http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/ajax/Ajax/Request/

Answer (score 0):

As MrYoshiji said, you can use ruby instead so do something like this:

```
var record_id = <%= record_id = 5 %>; 
if(<%= DataTable.find(record_id).value_of_record.nil? %>{
    ...
}else{
    ...
```

Initialising a variable in ruby returns the value so it will become just `var record_id = 73;` and the ruby variable is now available to the find method.